# issue with react ui communicating with node

Tags: node.js, reactjs

This is the react fetch:

```
   var json = {
     json: JSON.stringify({
         a: 1,
         b: 2
     }),
     delay: 3
 };

fetch('/saveInfo', {
         method: 'post',
         headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },

         body:  JSON.stringify(json.json)
     })
     .then(function (response) {
         return response.json();
     })
     .then(function (result) {
         alert(result);
          console.log("The file was saved!");
     })
     .catch (function (error) {
         console.log('Request failed');
     });
```

This is node:

```
<pre>
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function(app) {
  var router = express.Router();

  router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('from node');
    console.log(req);


    res.json({status: 'UP'});
  });

  app.use("/saveInfo", router);
}
</pre>
```

The code above doesn't work with the 2nd parameter to the fetch.

But when I execute it w/o the second parameter to fetch as below:

```
fetch('/saveInfo')
     .then(function (response) {
         return response.json();
     })
     .then(function (result) {
         alert(result);
          console.log("The file was saved!");
     })
     .catch (function (error) {
         console.log('Request failed');
     });
```

Works fine and is able to communicate to the node program.

Can any one help me with this what is wrong. I wanted to send the react's UI forms state t the node program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `add a handler for the POST requests` also.
In the fetch method for 1st case, you have given the method type as POST but node doesn't have any handling for that.
However, when you don't give the second parameter, it is considered as GET request and is intercepted by router.get.
Just add this in the node (before app.use line):

```
router.post("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log('from node');
  console.log(req);
  res.json({status: 'UP'});
});
```

It will enable node to listen for POST requests.

**Edit:** To have access to post request body params in router.post, you need `body-parser` package. Install this package and add these two lines before initializing the express router:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Read http://jilles.me/express-routing-the-beginners-guide/ for detailed explanation

Comment: I am also trying to receive the json that I am sending in the request from UI.<pre>body:  JSON.stringify(json.json)</pre>. How can I get the values in the router.post handler. I am trying using req.body which comes as undefined. req.params which comes blank?

Comment: You need body-parser package for this.
`app.use(bodyParser.json())`
`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`. Install the package and add these lines before initializing express router. Read http://jilles.me/express-routing-the-beginners-guide/ for detailed explanation.

Comment: Then I would suggest you to read this as well: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)